# require a file outside of node_modules with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to require a node module that is used in my app into my gruntfile.js but whatever I do i get : Cannot find module 'appjs/config

In the gruntfile I simply do : `var myconfig = require('appjs/config');`

But it just don't want to load, is there a way to import this files easily? I also tried various path but appjs is at the root where the gruntfile is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var myconfig = require('./appjs/config');
```

Seems like this should work, if appjs is in the same directory as your gruntfile.